# Spark Custom Partitioning in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, partition

I want to write a custom partitioner in spark and I'm working on java.

However I've noticed that the javaRDD class (or Dataset class) doesn't have a partitionBy(Partitioner) method like in scala. Only the javaPairRDD does. How am I supposed to partition RDDs or Datasets without this method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How am i supposed to partition RDDs or Datasets without this method?

You suppose to not:

- `Datasets` have no public concept of `Partitioner`. Instead you use `repartition` method which takes number of partitions and optional list of `Columns`. Partitioning method itself is not configurable (it is using hash partitioning with Murmur Hash).
- `RDDs`, other than "PairRDDs" (`JavaPairRDD` in Java, [`RDD[(_, _)]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) in Scala) cannot be repartitioned at all. If you want to re-partition other `RDD` you have to convert it to `PairRDD` first. If you don't have a good choice you can use `null` as value and the record as key.

Comment: So, all these online examples that use partitionBy are for the equivalent PairRDD scala class? Thanks! It's wasn't obvious to me since it seems types aren't explicitly stated in scala.